# A 2-D array display error in a member function

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I used a two dimension array to hold several strings, but it doesn't display

i know turbo C++ is a very old compiler and that i should not be using it but i have to use it for a school project

These two blocks are member functions for a class, i cannot paste the whole code, as it is around 500 lines long

```
   void algoin()
        {
            clrscr();
            do
            {
                if(agno<10)
                {
                    cout<<"\n\nShuffle Enter Algorithm:\n";
                    gets(algo[agno]);
                    agno++;
                    cout<<"\nAlgorithm has been entered";
                    cout<<"\nDo you want to add another?<y/n>\n>> ";
                    cin>>opt2;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"\n\nShuffle Algorithm Capacity is full"
                        <<"\n\nPress any key to continue";
                    getch();
                }
            }while(islower(opt2)=='y');
        }
        void algout()
        {
            clrscr();
            if(agno==0)
            {
                cout<<"\n\nNo Shuffle Algorithms present"
                    <<"\n\nPress any key to continue";
                return;
            }
            if(agno>0&&agno<10);
            {
                cout<<"\n\nShuffle Algorithm:\n ";
                cout<<algo[agno];  //Not displaying
                agno--;
                cout<<"\n\nPress any key to continue";
            }
        }
```

I need the string algo[][] to display and the value of agno to decrease after every time the algout() function is called.
Default value of agno is 0

How do i fix this??

Comment: Where do you declare algo[] at? What type is it? In the post you say algo is a string[][], but in the code it is being used as (presumably) a string[]. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BTables its declared as a private data member, where else could it be? Its is a character type 2-D array declared as char algo[10][50]

Comment: It could be declared just about anywhere else, that's why I asked. Also, nothing in the provided code implies this is actually a part of a class. Hence asking for a minimum example. Using char[][] can greatly complicate things when there are simpler solutions for what you're looking for. I'd suggest switching it out for a string[]

Comment: @BTables As mentioned above, its Turbo C++, the string data type does not exist here